# How to write joins in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How to write joins in django,i have gone through below django documentation ,but joins are not working for my model

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

and models/many_to_many/

and some blogs

My Model :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
     assign = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     doj = models.DateField()
     dob = models.DateField()

     class Meta:
        db_table = u'profile'

     def __str__(self):
         return  '%s %s %s %s' % ( self.name,self.assign,self.doj,self.dob)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return  u'%s %s %s %s' % ( self.name,self.assign,self.doj,self.dob)


     enter code here

class working(models.Model):
   w_name =models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_column='w_name')
   monday =  models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='monday', blank=True)
   tuesday =  models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='tuesday', blank=True)
   wednesday =  models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='wednesday', blank=True)

   class Meta:
        db_table = u'working'

   def __str__(self):
         return  '%s %s %s %s' % ( self.w_name,self.monday,self.tuesday,self.wednesday)

   def __unicode__(self):
         return  u'%s %s %s %s' % ( self.w_name,self.monday,self.tuesday,self.wednesday)
```

I am trying to do join between two tables profile and workingday

```
like m=working.objects.filter(name='sushanth').select_related()
```

if i run above query i'll get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/manager.py", line 129, in filter
    return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/query.py", line 498, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/query.py", line 516, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1675, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1569, in add_filter
    negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1737, in setup_joins
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are:  monday,  tuesday, wednesday,  w_name
```

I need to query where i can join working and profile.

support

`select working.*,profile.assign,profile.doj from working join profile where name=w_name ;`

I know django won't support joins,inner join  is also okay for me.

Can any one help on this.........................?

Comment: @user593132: Please format your question so that the code is readable (the `{}` button) otherwise it is very hard to read.

Comment: Let me suggest you a better name for `working` model: `WorkSchedule`. Always use CamelCase for model names. Your w_name column should be named `profile`, it points to profile, not to name. Do not change db_columnt, db_table names if there isn't big reason for that.

Comment: Now code is in readable format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please format your question so that the code is readable (the {} icon) otherwise it is very hard to read.

`working.objects.filter(name=` will fail because your `working` model doesn't have a `name` field.

From the docs you linked to:

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive
>   way to "follow" relationships in
>   lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs
>   for you automatically, behind the
>   scenes. To span a relationship, just
>   use the field name of related fields
>   across models, **separated by double
>   underscores**, until you get to the
>   field you want.

That translates to:

`m = working.objects.filter(w_name__name='sushanth').select_related()`

Comment: First i would appreciate for your response, I have change code into readable format. i try above still i am getting same error .........Thanks in advance

Comment: <code>>> from testapp.mod.models import *
>>> m=working.objects.filter(profile__name='sushanth')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1737, in setup_joins
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'profile' into field. Choices are: id, monday, tuesday, w_name, wednesday</code>

Comment: >>> m=working.objects.filter(w_name__name='sushanth')
>>> m.query.as_sql()
(u'SELECT `working`.`id`, `working`.`w_name`, `working`.`monday`, `working`.`tuesday`, `working`.`wednesday` FROM `working` WHERE `working`.`w_name` = %s ', ('sushanth',))

Comment: it doesn't giving any join query

Comment: m = working.objects.filter(w_name__name='sushanth').select_related()

Comment: Sure Done.one more question ,how to fetch all the w_name from which have assignee x .suppose 1. name = A,assign=x 2.Name=B,assign=X. now i want to fetch all the details assign from w_name . in sql : select working.* from working join profile where name=w_name && profile.assign=x

Comment: Thanks! m = working.objects.filter(w_name__name='sushanth', w_name__assign=X).select_related() ?

Comment: but it only works for sushanth,i want fetch all the users who are assigned to x

Comment: Oh, I see, name=w_name is the join?  `working.objects.filter(w_name__assign=X)`? is "all rows from table `working` who have a w_name assigned to X"